# $_POST and $_GET

Tags: post, get

I am trying to make all $_GET methods into $_POST on this page. I want **php?produktid=0**  to be **invisible** on the adress bar. 
How can I solve this?

This is an application and I want it to run on its own.

```
//PREVIOUS BUTTON
$index = $_GET['produktid'];
echo "<td>";
if ($index > 0) {
    echo '<a href="newarrivals.php?produktid=' . ($index - 1) . '"> <img style="margin-left: 77px;"  src="bilder/prev.png"> </a> ';
} else {
    echo '<a href="newarrivals.php?produktid=' . (count($array) - 1) . '"> <img style="margin-left: 77px;" src="prev.png"> </a> ';
}
echo "</td>";

//IF I AM ON PAGE ONE, ECHO THIS
if($_GET['produktid']==0){
    echo "<p>Page One</p>";
}

//IF I AM ON PAGE TWO, ECHO THIS
if($_GET['produktid']==2){
    echo "<p>Page Two</p>";
}

//IF I AM ON PAGE THREE, ECHO THIS
if($_GET['produktid']==3){
    echo "<p>Page Three</p>";
}

//NEXT BUTTON
echo "<td>";
if ($index < count($array) - 1) {
    echo '<a href="newarrivals.php?produktid=' . ($index + 1) . '"> <img style="margin-left: -70px;" src="bilder/next.png"> </a> ';
} else {
    echo '<a href="newarrivals.php?produktid=0"> <img style="margin-left: -70px;" src="next.png"> </a>';
}

echo "</td>";
echo "</table>";
echo "<div>";

?>
```

HERE IS HOW MY WHOLE PAGE LOOKS LIKE

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="sv-SE"/>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
<title>Images</title>
<style media="screen" type="text/css">
tr {display: inline-block;}
td {width: 120px;
    height: 90px;
    box-sizing: border-box;}
#Latest_products {
    height: 280px;
    width: 670px;
    background-color: grey;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
    }

</style>

</head>
<body>
<div id="latest_products">
<?php

    error_reporting(0);
        echo "<p><h1>New Arrivals</h1></p>";
        $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'webshop');
        mysql_set_charset("utf-8");


    //Identify Photo Sequences
        $array = array(
            0 => "picture1.jpg",
            1 => "picture2.jpg",
            2 => "kalle3.jpg",

    );



echo "<table>";

    //PREV BUTTON


        $index = $_GET['produktid'];
        echo "<td>";
                if ($index > 0) {
                    echo '<a href="newarrivals.php?produktid=' . ($index - 1) . '"> <img style="margin-left: 77px;"  src="bilder/prev.png"> </a> ';
                } else {
                    echo '<a href="newarrivals.php?produktid=' . (count($array) - 1) . '"> <img style="margin-left: 77px;" src="bilder/prev.png"> </a> ';
                }
        echo "</td>";



        //FOR PAGE 1 SHOW THIS
        if($_GET['produktid']==0){

                    $res = "SELECT * FROM produktlista ORDER BY produktankomst DESC LIMIT 0,3";
                    $result = $mysqli->query($res);

                    while($myRow = $result->fetch_array())
                        {   
                            echo "<tr>";
                            echo "<td><a href='./item.php?produktid=".$myRow["produktid"]."'> <img src=".$myRow["produktbild"]." height='132' width='132'> </a> </td>"; 
                            echo "<td style='display: block;'><a href='./item.php?produktid=".$myRow["produktid"]."'> <h4>".$myRow["produktnamn"]."</h4></a> </td>";
                            echo "</tr>";

                        }
        }

        //FOR PAGE 2 SHOW THIS
        if($_GET['produktid']==1){

                    $res = "SELECT * FROM produktlista ORDER BY produktankomst DESC LIMIT 1,3";
                    $result = $mysqli->query($res);

                    while($myRow = $result->fetch_array())
                        {   
                            echo "<tr>";
                            echo "<td><a href='./item.php?produktid=".$myRow["produktid"]."'> <img src=".$myRow["produktbild"]." height='132' width='132'> </a> </td>"; 
                            echo "<td style='display: block;'><a href='./item.php?produktid=".$myRow["produktid"]."'> <h4>".$myRow["produktnamn"]."</h4></a> </td>";
                            echo "</tr>";


                        }
        }

        //FOR PAGE 3 SHOW THIS

        if($_GET['produktid']==2){

                    $res = "SELECT * FROM produktlista ORDER BY produktankomst DESC LIMIT 2,3";
                    $result = $mysqli->query($res);

                    while($myRow = $result->fetch_array())
                        {   
                            echo "<tr>";
                            echo "<td><a href='./item.php?produktid=".$myRow["produktid"]."'> <img src=".$myRow["produktbild"]." height='132' width='132'> </a> </td>"; 
                            echo "<td style='display: block;'><a href='./item.php?produktid=".$myRow["produktid"]."'> <h4>".$myRow["produktnamn"]."</h4></a> </td>";
                            echo "</tr>";

                        }
        }



echo "<td>";

            //NEXT BUTTON

        if ($index < count($array) - 1) {
            echo '<a href="newarrivals.php?produktid=' . ($index + 1) . '"> <img style="margin-left: -70px;" src="bilder/next.png"> </a> ';
        } else {
            echo '<a href="newarrivals.php?produktid=0"> <img style="margin-left: -70px;" src="bilder/next.png"> </a>';
        }

        echo "</td>";
        echo "</table>";
        echo "<div>";

?>

</body>
</html>
```

After I change it looks like this now, and "PREV" "NEXT" links doesn't work now.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="sv-SE"/>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
<title>Images</title>
<style media="screen" type="text/css">
tr {display: inline-block;}
td {width: 120px;
    height: 90px;
    box-sizing: border-box;}
#senaste_produkter {
    height: 280px;
    width: 670px;
    background-color: grey;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
    }

</style>

</head>
<body>
<div id="senaste_produkter">
<?php

    //Databasuppkoppling - Visa senaste produkter ifrån databasen
    error_reporting(0);
        echo "<p><h1>New Arrivals</h1></p>";
        $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'webshop');
        mysql_set_charset("utf-8");


    //Identify picture sequences

        $array = array(
            0 => "picture1.jpg",
            1 => "picture2.jpg",
            2 => "kalle3.jpg",

    );



echo "<table>";

    //BACK LINK

        $index = $_GET['produktid'];
        echo "<td>";

                if ($index > 0) {
                      echo '<form action="newarrivals.php"><input type="hidden" name="produktid" value="' . ($index - 1) . '"><input style="margin-left: 77px;" src="bilder/prev.png"></form>';
                } else {
                    echo '<form action="newarrivals.php"><input type="hidden" name="produktid" value="'. (count($array) - 1) . '"> <img style="margin-left: 77px;" src="bilder/prev.png"> </form>';
                }
        echo "</td>";



        //IF I GO TO PAGE 3, SHOW THIS


        if($_GET['produktid']==0){

                    $res = "SELECT * FROM produktlista ORDER BY produktankomst DESC LIMIT 0,3";
                    $result = $mysqli->query($res);

                    while($myRow = $result->fetch_array())
                        {   
                            echo "<tr>";
                            echo "<td><a href='./item.php?produktid=".$myRow["produktid"]."'> <img src=".$myRow["produktbild"]." height='132' width='132'> </a> </td>"; 
                            echo "<td style='display: block;'><a href='./item.php?produktid=".$myRow["produktid"]."'> <h4>".$myRow["produktnamn"]."</h4></a> </td>";
                            echo "</tr>";

                        }
        }

        //IF I GO TO PAGE 2, SHOW THIS


        if($_GET['produktid']==1){

                    $res = "SELECT * FROM produktlista ORDER BY produktankomst DESC LIMIT 1,3";
                    $result = $mysqli->query($res);

                    while($myRow = $result->fetch_array())
                        {   
                            echo "<tr>";
                            echo "<td><a href='./item.php?produktid=".$myRow["produktid"]."'> <img src=".$myRow["produktbild"]." height='132' width='132'> </a> </td>"; 
                            echo "<td style='display: block;'><a href='./item.php?produktid=".$myRow["produktid"]."'> <h4>".$myRow["produktnamn"]."</h4></a> </td>";
                            echo "</tr>";


                        }
        }

        //IF I GO TO PAGE 3, SHOW THIS
        if($_GET['produktid']==2){

                    $res = "SELECT * FROM produktlista ORDER BY produktankomst DESC LIMIT 2,3";
                    $result = $mysqli->query($res);

                    while($myRow = $result->fetch_array())
                        {   
                            echo "<tr>";
                            echo "<td><a href='./item.php?produktid=".$myRow["produktid"]."'> <img src=".$myRow["produktbild"]." height='132' width='132'> </a> </td>"; 
                            echo "<td style='display: block;'><a href='./item.php?produktid=".$myRow["produktid"]."'> <h4>".$myRow["produktnamn"]."</h4></a> </td>";
                            echo "</tr>";

                        }
        }



echo "<td>";


            //NEXT PAGE


        if ($index < count($array) - 1) {
            echo '<form action="newarrivals.php"><input type="hidden" name="produktid" value="' . ($index + 1) . '"> <img style="margin-left: -70px;" src="bilder/next.png"> </a> ';
        } else {
            echo '<form action="newarrivals.php"> <img style="margin-left: -70px;" src="bilder/next.png"> </a>';
        }

        echo "</td>";
        echo "</table>";
        echo "<div>";

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have to use forms instead of links. Then you can put the parameters into hidden inputs.

Comment: Or you could use AJAX and update the page without reloading.

Comment: can you show an example using form instead of links from my code?

Comment: Do you have a specific reason why you want to use POST instead of GET?

Comment: @YacoZaragoza He said it in the question: he doesn't want the parameter to go into the URL bar.

Comment: I saw that, The questions is "Why" he does not want them to show (Security or Just visuals).. If its just for visuals he might be interested on using pretty URLS thought htaccess

Comment: @YacoZaragoza. I want to add this image carousel into another page and I want it to be independent from the other parts of the page.

Comment: @Danny Changing from `GET` to `POST` won't do that. Maybe you should use an `<iframe>`

Comment: I would recommend you look at `htaccess` and `mod_rewrite`.

Comment: I think that would work, but can I make the Iframe responsive for mobile devices? And make it without scrollbars etc?

Comment: @Danny is seems to me that you can create your Image Carousel in a include file and the include the file in the pages  that you need to show it.. What does this have to do with the GET and POST question you asked?

Comment: @Zaragoza I thought that including pages doesn't make the carousel to work independent inside another pages. Does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use forms instead of links, and put the parameters into hidden inputs. So change

```
echo '<a href="newarrivals.php?produktid=' . ($index - 1) . '"> <img style="margin-left: 77px;"  src="bilder/prev.png"> </a> ';
```

to:

```
echo '<form action="newarrivals.php" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="produktid" value="' . ($index - 1) . '"><input type="image" style="margin-left: 77px;" src="bilder/prev.png"></form>';
```

and change all the other links similarly.

Here's the whole rewritten script:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="sv-SE"/>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
<title>Images</title>
<style media="screen" type="text/css">
tr {display: inline-block;}
td {width: 120px;
    height: 90px;
    box-sizing: border-box;}
#senaste_produkter {
    height: 280px;
    width: 670px;
    background-color: grey;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
    }

</style>

</head>
<body>
<div id="senaste_produkter">
<?php

    //Databasuppkoppling - Visa senaste produkter ifrån databasen
    error_reporting(0);
        echo "<p><h1>New Arrivals</h1></p>";
        $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'webshop');
        mysql_set_charset("utf-8");


    //Identify picture sequences

        $array = array(
            0 => "picture1.jpg",
            1 => "picture2.jpg",
            2 => "kalle3.jpg",

    );



echo "<table>";

    //BACK LINK

        $index = $_GET['produktid'];
        echo "<tr><td>";

                if ($index > 0) {
                      echo '<form action="newarrivals.php" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="produktid" value="' . ($index - 1) . '"><input type="image" style="margin-left: 77px;" src="bilder/prev.png"></form>';
                } else {
                    echo '<form action="newarrivals.php" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="produktid" value="'. (count($array) - 1) . '"> <input type="image" style="margin-left: 77px;" src="bilder/prev.png"> </form>';
                }
        echo "</td></tr>";



        //IF I GO TO PAGE 3, SHOW THIS


        if($_GET['produktid']==0){

                    $res = "SELECT * FROM produktlista ORDER BY produktankomst DESC LIMIT 0,3";
                    $result = $mysqli->query($res);

                    while($myRow = $result->fetch_array())
                        {   
                            echo "<tr>";
                            echo "<td><a href='./item.php?produktid=".$myRow["produktid"]."'> <img src=".$myRow["produktbild"]." height='132' width='132'> </a> </td>"; 
                            echo "<td style='display: block;'><a href='./item.php?produktid=".$myRow["produktid"]."'> <h4>".$myRow["produktnamn"]."</h4></a> </td>";
                            echo "</tr>";

                        }
        }

        //IF I GO TO PAGE 2, SHOW THIS


        if($_GET['produktid']==1){

                    $res = "SELECT * FROM produktlista ORDER BY produktankomst DESC LIMIT 1,3";
                    $result = $mysqli->query($res);

                    while($myRow = $result->fetch_array())
                        {   
                            echo "<tr>";
                            echo "<td><a href='./item.php?produktid=".$myRow["produktid"]."'> <img src=".$myRow["produktbild"]." height='132' width='132'> </a> </td>"; 
                            echo "<td style='display: block;'><a href='./item.php?produktid=".$myRow["produktid"]."'> <h4>".$myRow["produktnamn"]."</h4></a> </td>";
                            echo "</tr>";


                        }
        }

        //IF I GO TO PAGE 3, SHOW THIS
        if($_GET['produktid']==2){

                    $res = "SELECT * FROM produktlista ORDER BY produktankomst DESC LIMIT 2,3";
                    $result = $mysqli->query($res);

                    while($myRow = $result->fetch_array())
                        {   
                            echo "<tr>";
                            echo "<td><a href='./item.php?produktid=".$myRow["produktid"]."'> <img src=".$myRow["produktbild"]." height='132' width='132'> </a> </td>"; 
                            echo "<td style='display: block;'><a href='./item.php?produktid=".$myRow["produktid"]."'> <h4>".$myRow["produktnamn"]."</h4></a> </td>";
                            echo "</tr>";

                        }
        }



echo "<tr><td>";


            //NEXT PAGE


        if ($index < count($array) - 1) {
            echo '<form action="newarrivals.php" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="produktid" value="' . ($index + 1) . '"> <input type="image" style="margin-left: -70px;" src="bilder/next.png">';
        } else {
            echo '<form action="newarrivals.php" method="post"> <input type="image" style="margin-left: -70px;" src="bilder/next.png">';
        }

        echo "</td></tr>";
        echo "</table>";
        echo "<div>";

?>

</body>
</html>
```